# Powershell Adding Multiple users based on a template

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I was wondering if someone could help me Importing users from a CSV or Excel file to AD based on a Templateuser. However i have no idea how to get the SamAccountNAme and Display name row for row from a CSV file so i don't have to manually change it.

```
$UserInstance = Get-ADuser -Identity "SaraDavis"
New-ADUser -SAMAccountName "EllenAdams" -Instance $userInstance -DisplayName "EllenAdams"
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSV file would look something like this. Let's assume this information goes into `c:\test\users.csv`.

```
SamAccountName,DisplayName
trevor,Trevor Sullivan
nancy,Nancy Drew
billy,Billy Bob
```

The, script would look something like this:

```
# 1. Get a reference to the template user, with all properties
$TemplateUser = Get-ADUser -Identity TemplateUser -Properties *;

# 2. Import the CSV file
$Data = Import-Csv -Path c:\test\users.csv;

# 3. Create a new user for each row / item in the CSV file
foreach ($Item in $Data) {
    New-ADUser -Identity $Item.SamAccountName -DisplayName $Item.DisplayName -Parameter1 $TemplateUser.Property1 ... ... ... ...;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried executing the script below....  But for some reason it gives me the following error. 
I seperately ran the first line to check if it does find the user and it does execute it without a problem.

Comment: New-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Identity'.
At C:\ScriptTest.ps1:4 char:25
+     New-ADUser -Identity <<<<  $Item.SamAccountName -DisplayName $Item.DisplayName -Parameter1 $TemplateUser
1;
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Comment: New-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Identity'.
At C:\ScriptTest.ps1:4 char:25
+     New-ADUser -Identity <<<<  $Item.SamAccountName -DisplayName $Item.DisplayName -Parameter1 $TemplateUser
1;
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Comment: Sorry, that was just supposed to be an example. It looks like `New-ADUser` has the `-SamAccountName` parameter.

Comment: would it be something like this?  $TemplateUser = Get-ADUser -SamAccountName TemplateUser -Properties *;
$Data = Import-Csv -Path c:\testlijst.csv;
foreach ($Item in $Data) {
    New-ADUser  -SamAccountName $Item.SamAccountName -DisplayName $Item.DisplayName -Parameter1 $TemplateUser.Property1;
}